# SQL count second column for-each unique row of first column

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have this sample many-to-many table for students & subjects in a university

```
student | subject
-----------------
James   | English
James   | Physics
Paul    | Mathematics
Paul    | English
Paul    | English
Paul    | French
Jake    | French
Jake    | Mathematics
Paul    | English
```

I need to know the SQL query for getting the count of subjects for each student like

```
student | # of subjects
------------------------
James   |   2
Paul    |   3
Jake    |   2
```

Comment: hi can you share the table details.

Comment: You all need is group by student and count distinct:

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is `GROUP BY student` and `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT student, COUNT(DISTINCT subject) AS "# of subjects" 
FROM students_subjects
GROUP BY student;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to group

```
    CREATE TABLE `student_subject` (
      `name` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
      `subject` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `student_subject`
    --

    INSERT INTO `student_subject` (`name`, `subject`) VALUES
    ('James', 'English'),
    ('James', 'Physics'),
    ('Paul', 'Mathematics'),
    ('Paul', 'English'),
    ('Paul', 'English'),
    ('Paul', 'French'),
    ('Jake', 'Mathematics'),
    ('Jake', 'French');

 SELECT name, COUNT(distinct subject) AS "subject_count" 
 FROM student_subject
 GROUP BY name,subject order by name desc

#########output##############

 Name     subject_count
('Jake' , 2),
('James', 2),
('Paul' , 3);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT student, count(*) 
FROM table
GROUP BY student
```

Comment: Please add some description with code/query to help understanding how it will fix the problem.

Comment: Is it really needed an explanation for such a simple query? Moreover, a one line explanation like 'All you need is GROUP BY students and COUNT' is the accepted answer while this gets downvoted? I don't think a phrase like that adds any value to the answer... I'm relatively new to so, just asking

Answer (score -2):

You need to group the select by student:

```
SELECT student, count(*) as NumberOfSubjects
FROM table_name
GROUP BY student
```

Answer (score -3):

```
Select student , count(subject) from Table Group by student
```